# ImageViews in LinearLayout - messing up the scale

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I been struggeling with this for a whole day now. I want 3 Image Views in my LinearLayout. As you can see the scale is not correct at all. All of my icons have a size of 24x24 px. Been experimenting with different propertiers inside of my ImageViews.

Here is my XML-code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_home_black_24px" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_help_black_24px"
               />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ations"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24px"
                />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: prev]

Comment: Have you tried changing the `"fill_parent"` attribute of each `ImageView` ? Fill parent will force the `ImageView` to fit into que parent's width and height..

Comment: Maybe the best way to go for you, is try to use a `wrap_content` attribute in width and height, or well, use the `dp` equivalent of `24px`

Comment: Yea first I had it set to wrap_content but that didn't make it any better. I even tried setting layout_width and layout_height to 24dp. Still messed up the scale...

Comment: Please check my response, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your code on a layout file in my `Android Studio`, an it seems that the `weight` and `scaleType` attributes are messing up your view. This is how I declared a 24 by 24 `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ations"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"
    />
```

You can check full doc about `weight` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight), but what is basically saying is that if you put `weight` on several attributes under a `LinearLayout`, you're adding a priority to grow when the screen does. Since the 3 `ImageViews` have 1 as `weight`, they grow with the same priority, and since the `fill_parent` is being called also, they will force to fit in the parent layout params, looking oddly.

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your ImageView's width to "0dp" and replace background to src  like this :

```
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ations"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24px"
            />
```